# Error: implicit declaration of function 'FIPS_crypto_set_id_callback'

Tags: openssl, fips

I am getting the following error when try to integrate upgrade OpenSSL from version 1.0.2h to 1.0.2j.

```
o_init.c:77:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'FIPS_crypto_set_id_callback' is
    invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
FIPS_crypto_set_id_callback(CRYPTO_thread_id);
```

Comment: Please show how you configured the library. That is, what was the configure line, and what did configure output. A question might also be helpful so we provide an answer to what you are having trouble with.

Comment: Was able to fix the issue by adding -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration to the CFLAG.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that does not fix the issue. I believe you simply moved the problem around.

Comment: Yes that was a workaround to build the code.Since the openssl configuration code has changed in version 1.0.2j and also the default configuration.

Answer (score 2):

That method call is wrapped with "#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_DEPRECATED", which looks like code that has been back-ported from the 1.1.0 branch.

The change history of 1.1.0 implies that they have been changing code to improve the management of the OpenSSL API level.   You could try adding "no-deprecated" to your "configure" parameters, but I'm dubious about that since it looks to be a 1.1.0 configuration option.  Alternatively patch the source to remove the new 3 lines of code, since your previous version wasn't calling the deprecated method anyway.

```
--- a/crypto/o_init.c
+++ b/crypto/o_init.c
@@ -73,9 +73,6 @@
     done = 1;
 #ifdef OPENSSL_FIPS
     FIPS_set_locking_callbacks(CRYPTO_lock, CRYPTO_add_lock);
-# ifndef OPENSSL_NO_DEPRECATED
-    FIPS_crypto_set_id_callback(CRYPTO_thread_id);
-# endif
     FIPS_set_error_callbacks(ERR_put_error, ERR_add_error_vdata);
     FIPS_set_malloc_callbacks(CRYPTO_malloc, CRYPTO_free);
     RAND_init_fips();
```

Comment: I've just had this pointed out to me as the reason for the callback being added.  [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mailing.openssl.dev/rLNlxFW0AhE/wHm3oBROBQAJ).  So please be aware that it may depend on the FIPS module that you are using, and that it may be better to add a function prototype at the top of o_init.c to avoid a problem in the future (with later code changes).